# `&str` as pointing to non-contiguous portion of memory

Tags: rust

Is something like possible in `rust`?

```rs
fn replace_abracadabra(s: &str) -> &str {
    if s.starts_with("abracadabra") {
        "i am static" + s.chars().last().unwrap() 
    } else {
        s
    }
}
```

Here, `"i am static" + s.chars().last().unwrap()` is all borrowed, but is now a non-contiguous block of memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, slices (both string and array slices) are contiguous by definition.

You also cannot borrow unless you have an owned value to borrow *from.*  In this case you are trying to construct a new value and then return a reference to it, which is not possible in Rust.

The two pieces of information you're trying to concatenate are indeed borrowed, but the concatenation creates a *new value* that contains non-borrowed information.  Even if you let the string data live where it is, the information "glue these two strings together" cannot be borrowed.  You could return a `(&str, &str)` for example -- the tuple is an owned value that contains two borrowed slices in it.

This function should probably return an owned `String` value.  You could also return a `Cow<'_, str>` which would allow you to borrow `s` in the `else` block without copying, but return an owned value in the first case.